# javax.mail not including Sender Name in emails

Tags: java, smtp, jakarta-mail, mail-sender

No matter what I try, I can't get the Sender Name to show up in the outgoing mails sent through the javax.mail Session class.

Please note that I'm using Rhino so there's a mixture of javascript and java here, but the code problem exists in pure java as well.

```
var _java = JavaImporter(javax.mail, javax.mail.internet, java.util);

        var props = new _java.Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", myHost);
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
        props.put("mail.smtp.user", myUserName);
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", 465);
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
                  "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
        props.put("mail.smtp.ssl", "true");

        var session = _java.Session.getInstance(props);

        var message = _java.MimeMessage(session);
        message.setSender(
            new _java.InternetAddress("myEmailAddress", "My Full Name")
        );
        message.setRecipients(
            _java.Message.RecipientType.TO,
            [new _java.InternetAddress("anyAddress@anydomain.com", true)]
        );
        message.setText("Testing");
        message.setSubject("Test");
        message.setSentDate(new Date());
        var t = session.getTransport("smtp");
        t.connect(myUserName, myPassword);
        t.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
```

The email that comes through has:

```
Sender: Personal Name <email@domain.com>
```

But the from is always:

```
From: email@domain.com
```

Therefore, mail clients like Outlook and Gmail aren't plucking out the name.

I've tried adding

```
props.put("mail.smtp.from", "Full Name <email@domain.com>")
```

but this doesn't make any difference.

Anybody have any experience with this bug?

Thanks.

Comment: Show complete self-standing example.

Comment: what are you using for an SMTP server? Does it support "personal name"s?

Comment: I can send through command line fine, so the server supports it.  The problem is with the javax library somewhere.

Comment: I'll post a complete example, but have to tease it apart so as to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What a pain.

The bug was that I was using message.setSender instead of message.setFrom.

Changing that solved it.

Comment: I am using setFrom. The header is there in mail source, however, thunderbird is not presenting it in the from name. Apple mails does. No idea what the difference is.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to clear it as I have the same issue

```
// sender the email string example test@test.com

message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(sender));
```